# Bitwise operators in C: how this function works?

Tags: c, operators, bit-manipulation

*I can't figure out how this functions works:*

```
void print3bytes(unsigned char s[],unsigned len)
{
    unsigned char *end;
    for(end=s+len-len%3;  s<end;  s=s+3 )
        printf("%x ",  s[0]|s[1]<<8  |  s[2]<<16); 
    putchar('\n'); 
}
```

how does this work for this example:

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char s[] = "\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9A\xBC\xDE\xFF";
    print3bytes(s, 8);
    return 0;
}
```

Could someone please explain?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: this:   s[0] | s[1]<<8  |  s[2]<<16;

Comment: What part of that do you not understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression combines:

- The first byte `s[0]`
- The second byte `s[1]` shifted (`<<´) 8 bits to the left
- The third byte `s[2]` shifted (`<<`) 16 bits to the left

using bitwise-or (`|`).

So, when `s` contains 0x12, 0x34, 0x56 as its first bytes, it computes

```
0x12 | (0x34 << 8) | (0x56 << 16)
  ^       ^             ^
  |       |             |
s[0]     s[1]         s[2]
```

which is

```
0x12 | 0x3400 | 0x560000
```

or `0x563412`. Basically it's unpacking (decoding, de-serializing, de-marshaling, whatever) a 24-bit integer in [little-endian format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) from the start of `s`.

Comment: @Alex You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark if you like it.

Answer (score 1):

```
s[0] | s[1]<<8  |  s[2]<<16
```

Let's say s[2] is 0xff (255), s[1] is 0xaa (170) and s[0] is 0x11 (17). If you shift s[2] 16 bits, you get:

```
0xff0000
```

If you shift s[1] by 8bits, you get:

```
0x00aa00
```

And if you or these together you get

```
0xffaa00
```

And or this with s[0]:

```
0xffaa11
```